# Mouseleave Issue on Tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ipad

Is there an alternative to `'mouseleave'` on tablet.

Scenario:

On Desktop a list item is shown on `'mouseenter'` and hidden on `'mouseleave'`.

On Tablet, the `'mouseenter'` shows the list item but does not remove it when the user clicks else where.

I do not want to use touchstart and touchend.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click handler on document with jquery. In this new handler hide the listitems.

```
$(document).on('click:not(#list)', function() {
    // hide listitems
});
```

Something like this.. This might not be the best solution, but it is one.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to make an alternative interaction for touch devices. The easiest way to it would be to attach an event listener to the document, which would hide the list items when user taps outside of the list.

```
$(document).on('click.list', function (e) {
    var $list = $(".list");

    if (!$list.is(e.target) && $list.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $list.hide();
    }
});
```

It's a good practice to namespace the event (`'click.list'`) whenever you're attaching an event listener to document.

The if condition checks whether the event target is the list or one of its children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .hover as shown below:

```
$('.foo').hover(
function () {
$(this).find('h1').addClass("hover").end().find('input').focus();            
        },
function () {
$(this).find('h1').removeClass("hover").end().find('input').val('');            
        }
    );
```